# Compressor library can't find photo File after creating it with Camera

Tags: android, android-camera-intent

I'm trying to compress an image taken with the camera, right before passing it to a `Webview`, with the [Compressor](https://github.com/zetbaitsu/Compressor) library. 
For some reason, the library can't find the file right after taking the picture. 
I've used [this library](https://github.com/ptine/WebToMobileApp) to take pictures from camera, and I'm running it on a Redmi 4 Prime with Android Marshmallow 6.0.1.

This is the file creation Part. You can see I'm not using a `File.createTempFile` method because for some reason it wouldn't simply work on my device but work with others, so I'm generating a unique filename instead.

```
private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = timeStamp;
    File storageDir = this.activity.getApplicationContext().getExternalFilesDir(null);
    File imageFile = new File(storageDir + "/" + imageFileName + ".jpg");
    return imageFile;
}
```

and a snippet from `onActivityResult`

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {

        if(resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED){
            Utils.getFilePathCallback().onReceiveValue(null);
            Utils.setFilePathCallback(null);
            return;
        }

        if (requestCode != Utils.INPUT_FILE_REQUEST_CODE || Utils.getFilePathCallback() == null) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            return;
        }

        Uri[] results = null;

        // Check that the response is a good one
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (data == null) {
                // If there is not data, then we may have taken a photo
                if (Utils.getCameraPhotoPath() != null) {
                    File actualImage = new File(Utils.getCameraPhotoPath());
                    File compressedFileImage = null;
                    try {
                        compressedFileImage = new Compressor(this).setMaxWidth(640)
                                .setMaxHeight(480)
                                .setQuality(75)
                                .setCompressFormat(Bitmap.CompressFormat.WEBP)
                                .setDestinationDirectoryPath(actualImage.getParent())
                                .compressToFile(actualImage);
                    } catch (IOException e ){
                        Log.d("Compressor", e.toString());
                    }
                    //Uri compressedFileUri = Uri.fromFile(compressedFileImage);
                    //results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(Utils.getCameraPhotoPath())};
                    results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(compressedFileImage.getAbsolutePath())};
                }
```

About this snippet.

```
File actualImage = new File(Utils.getCameraPhotoPath());
                    File compressedFileImage = null;
                    try {
                        compressedFileImage = new Compressor(this).setMaxWidth(640)
                                .setMaxHeight(480)
                                .setQuality(75)
                                .setCompressFormat(Bitmap.CompressFormat.WEBP)
                                .setDestinationDirectoryPath(actualImage.getParent())
                                .compressToFile(actualImage);
                    } catch (IOException e ){
                        Log.d("Compressor", e.toString());
                    }
```

`actualImage` is always defined, the picture is saved on the phone in the "appname/files" folder. But **`compressedFileImage` is always null**, as it fails with an **FileNotFoundException**.

If I compare the two paths, they're equal, so I don't understand why it should fail.
I've already inserted `uses-permission` in the manifest file, and I can write and read on external storage. A bit weird since `this.activity.getApplicationContext().getExternalFilesDir(null);` doesn't save in the external storage but in the internal one instead (the app still creates a "appname/files" folder in the external).
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you use [this code](https://github.com/ptine/WebToMobileApp/blob/master/app/src/main/java/paolotine/it/webtomobileapp/MyChromeClient.java#L49) to request camera photo, you may [need a FileProvider](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47448794/192373). It is also a good practice to write something to the file returned by **createImageFile()** before you pass the URI to `MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT`.

Comment: @AlexCohn thank you so much for your input. I've managed to resolve the problem by using FileProvider in the answer you posted.