# Unable to get captured image uri

Tags: java, android, android-camera-intent

I am trying to get Captured image Uri but not getting this below code how I get uri. Toast message giving me null result

```
 Button b=findViewById(R.id.button);
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i=new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(i,2);
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Toast.makeText(Authentication.this,""+data.getData(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: You will not get an uri. You will get a bitmap with this intent in this way.

Comment: @aj-pawar.

I think you need to check this answer. 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/47448794/2215364

and blackapps is right, the code which you have mentioned in question will give you bitmap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Android version LOLLIPOP you can not get the URI directly for security reasons try this-

```
    private static Uri getSharableImageUri(Context context) {
File outputDir = context.getCacheDir();
File imagePath = new File(outputDir, context.getString(R.string.app_name));
if (!imagePath.exists()) {
    imagePath.mkdir();
}
File tempFile = new File(imagePath, "image.jpg");
Uri uri = null;
try {
    if (!tempFile.exists()) {
        tempFile.createNewFile();
    }
    uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, context.getPackageName() + ".fileprovider", tempFile);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return uri;
}
```

And in your button's click listener use this-

```
     Button b=findViewById(R.id.button);
b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
       Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
try {
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {

        mImageCaptureUri = getSharableImageUri(context);
    }
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        intent.setClipData(ClipData.newRawUri("", mImageCaptureUri));

    }
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mImageCaptureUri);
    intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 2);

} catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
    }
});
```

}

And get the URI in onActivityResult if the result is successful -

```
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode==2) {
    Toast.makeText(Authentication.this,""+data.getData(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE && 
                              resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (data != null) {
        Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");

        Uri imageUri = getImageUri(getApplicationContext(), bitmap);
        }
    }
```

Call this method to get uri fom bitmap:

```
public Uri getImageUri(Context inContext, Bitmap myImage) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    myImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
    String path = Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.getContentResolver(), 
    myImage, "Title", null);
    return Uri.parse(path);
}
```

Comment: but sir  i wanna store image to firebase_Storage that time we need Uri

Comment: @AjPawar you need file provider. Then you can get file uri and upload to firebase storage.